# How to refactor Typescript code with dynamic variables to pass linting?

Tags: typescript

How to refactor creating dynamic variable in Typescript? Because obj.identifier is not known it is an error to assign value... what would be the correct approach to refactor?

```
interface test {
  [key: string]: any
}

class Test implements test {
  #obj: any
  constructor(obj: any) {
   this.#obj = obj
  }
  test(value: string) {
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(value: string) => void'
    this[this.#obj.identifier as keyof Test] = value
  }
}
```

I would like to use it like:

```
const t = new Test({identifier: "a"})
t.test("aa")
t.a 
=> "aa"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by having a container object.

```
interface cType {
  a: any
  b: any
  c: any
}

class Test {
  container: cType = {}
  ...
}
```

... and then populate container using dynamic properties and values.